# How to reverse a matrix in R?

Tags: r

I have a simple matrix like:

```
> a = matrix(c(c(1:10),c(10:1)), ncol=2)
> a
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   10
 [2,]    2    9
 [3,]    3    8
 [4,]    4    7
 [5,]    5    6
 [6,]    6    5
 [7,]    7    4
 [8,]    8    3
 [9,]    9    2
[10,]   10    1
```

I would like to get this result:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   10    1
 [2,]    9    2
 [3,]    8    3
 [4,]    7    4
 [5,]    6    5
 [6,]    5    6
 [7,]    4    7
 [8,]    3    8
 [9,]    2    9
[10,]    1    10
```

The exact reverse of the matrix. How can I get it?
Thanks

Comment: From the example you used, it's not clear whether you want the columns or the rows reversed. Just for the record, Dirk's solution reverses the order of the rows, while mine reverses the order of columns.

Comment: Came to say exactly this. I ended up using Josh's solution myself, as I was looking to reverse columns. Perhaps you can edit this so you have a matrix more like matrix(1:20, nrow = 10)

Comment: If you apply either of Josh or Dirk's solutions to an array with singleton dimensions, R will collapse them. You can wrap the calls like so: `array(reversing.thing, dim = dim(thing))` to keep it from happening.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `rev` with `apply`:

```
> a <- matrix(c(1:10,10:1), ncol=2)
> a
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   10
 [2,]    2    9
 [3,]    3    8
 [4,]    4    7
 [5,]    5    6
 [6,]    6    5
 [7,]    7    4
 [8,]    8    3
 [9,]    9    2
[10,]   10    1
> b <- apply(a, 2, rev)
> b
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   10    1
 [2,]    9    2
 [3,]    8    3
 [4,]    7    4
 [5,]    6    5
 [6,]    5    6
 [7,]    4    7
 [8,]    3    8
 [9,]    2    9
[10,]    1   10
```

Comment: Why not two times rotate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16497058/54964 such as `rotate = function(mat) t(mat[nrow(mat):1,,drop=FALSE])` from docs archive.

Comment: It's much slower than the `a[, ncol(a):1]` approach, but has the advantage that it can be done inline to declare `b`: `b = apply(matrix(c(1:10, 10:1), 10, 2), 2, rev)`

Comment: @dirk-eddelbuettel Thx a lot. This is a very nice and perfect replacer of `matlab::flipud`. In the usage of that function, people may face many errors, but in your solution, that is very neat and perfect, no errors appears. One such error for flipud is `error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'flipud': Error in .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable) : 
  trying to get slot "group" from an object (class "nonstandardGenericFunction") that is not an S4 object`. Once more, many thanks Dirk. Really, your solution is life-saver for many cases.

Answer (score 37):

```
a[nrow(a):1,]
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,]   10    1
#  [2,]    9    2
#  [3,]    8    3
#  [4,]    7    4
#  [5,]    6    5
#  [6,]    5    6
#  [7,]    4    7
#  [8,]    3    8
#  [9,]    2    9
# [10,]    1   10
```

Comment: This is the fastest of the solutions listed here. `a[dim(a)[1]:1, ]` is (marginally) faster still, if less readable.

Answer (score 12):

Here's one way:

```
a[, rev(seq_len(ncol(a)))]
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   10    1
 [2,]    9    2
 [3,]    8    3
 [4,]    7    4
 [5,]    6    5
 [6,]    5    6
 [7,]    4    7
 [8,]    3    8
 [9,]    2    9
[10,]    1   10
```

Comment: This also works for any higher number of dimensions in an array, thankfully--just add more commas and replace `ncol()` with `dim()[n]`.

Comment: why not just `ncol(a):1`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico While I’m no R expert, your solution seems to work and to be more elegant to me, so I’d say add that as an answer!

Comment: @doncherry thanks, but it's the same as Per's solution (on rows instead of columns)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Actually, your solution and Per's solution do completely different things (though with the example data given here, the result is the same). Your answer and mine reflect the matrix using a vertical  line of symmetry, while Per's reflects it across a horizontal line of  symmetry. (There's no telling for sure which the OP wanted, though given that they accepted Dirk's answer, it looks like they wanted what he and Per gave them, rather than what you and I did.)

Comment: Yes, I meant the logic/syntax is the same -- it's not hard to translate Per's approach to go column-wise depending on what's needed

Comment: @MichaelChirico Sure. I didn't mean to sound pedantic/lecturing. I just remember this question having been unclear at the time, and was really clarifying (as much for me as anyone else) the difference!

Comment: no offense taken at all, it's good to keep a record in case anyone else loses the thread of thinking in the future :)