# Extract the anti-diagonals from an array

Tags: arrays, r, loops

I want to extract the anti-diagonals of an array

```
m=array(1:18,c(3,3,2))
```

My best shot

```
k=dim(m)[3]

mn=matrix(nrow = k, ncol = 3)

for (i in 1:k){
  mn=diag(m[,,i][3:1,1:3])
  }
```

This returns `12 14 16`, the anti-diagonal of the second matrix in the array. I want to achieve this

```
[1] 3  5  7
[2] 12 14 16
```

I want the “anti-diags” as arrays

Manually `diag(m[,,1][3:1,1:3])` and `diag(m[,,2][3:1,1:3])` works fine, but the array I’m working with is `dim(c(3,3,22))`, so I thought "loop!"

MQ: How to extract the anti-diagonals from an array using the loop? (better and elegant  solutions are more than welcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
mn <- array(NA, dim=dim(m))
for (i in 1:dim(m)[3]){
   mn[,,i]=diag(m[,,i][cbind(3:1,1:3)])
              }
```

It was unclear whether you want the "anti-diag" to become the new diag, but that is what your code suggested as the intent. The form `matrix[cbind(vec1,vec2)]` pulls the (R,C) referenced elements from the matrix.

If you do not want them as arrays then this is an alternate result:

```
 mn <- array(NA, dim=c(2,3))
     for (i in 1:dim(m)[3]){
        mn[i,]=m[,,i][cbind(3:1,1:3)]
                            }
 mn
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5    7
[2,]   12   14   16
```

This is a loopless way of getting the same values:

```
 m[cbind( rep(3:1,2), rep(1:3,2), rep(1:2,each=3)) ]
[1]  3  5  7 12 14 16
```

Comment: Thank you @DWin. The second solution is what I'm looking for, I edited the question. Thanks for explaining the cbind in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lapply` across the third dimension and extract the anti-diagonal by first rotating the matrix ( [see this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497058/1478381) ) by reversing the column order and taking the diagonal of that. Basically like this...

```
out <- lapply( 1:dim(m)[3] , function(x) diag( t( apply( m[,,x] , 2 , rev ) ) ) )
[[1]]
[1] 3 5 7

[[2]]
[1] 12 14 16
```

If you need them glued together as an array then use `do.call`...

```
do.call( rbind , out )
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5    7
[2,]   12   14   16
```

In this particular case, a `for` loop will be *much* quicker (benchmark it) and you should use @DWin's answer.

It occurs to me that we can simplfy this a bit and avoid using lists and bad use of `lapply` (by assuming that`m` is available outside the scope of `lapply`) because we can also simply `apply` across the third dimension of your matrices. So we can `apply` once to rotate the matrices, then take the `diag` of each rotated matrix like so...

```
rotM <- apply( m , 2:3 , rev )    
out <- t( apply( rotM , 3 , diag ) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    5    7
[2,]   12   14   16
```

Comment: @SimononO101, one word awesome

Comment: @Adam thanks. I added a second solution which I think is a lot neater.

Comment: @SimononO101, Indeed DWin's quicker. But using lapply is awesome (for me) because I would not think of the ‘apply family’ in such cases

Comment: @Adam: The swap of `sapply` for `lapply` would probably make the output a matrix although it would likely be column-oriented so `t(sapply(...))` should give same output as `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))`.