# Unexpected apply function behaviour in R

Tags: r, apply

I've discovered a surprising behaviour by `apply` that I wonder if anyone can explain.  Lets take a simple matrix:

```
> (m = matrix(1:8,ncol=4))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8
```

We can flip it vertically thus:

```
> apply(m, MARGIN=2, rev)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    6    8
[2,]    1    3    5    7
```

This applies the `rev()` vector reversal function iteratively to each column. But when we try to apply rev by row we get:

```
> apply(m, MARGIN=1, rev)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7    8
[2,]    5    6
[3,]    3    4
[4,]    1    2
```

.. a 90 degree anti-clockwise rotation!  Apply delivers the same result using `FUN=function(v) {v[length(v):1]}` so it is definitely not rev's fault.

Any explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns
>   an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1.

From that perspective, this behaviour is not a bug whatsoever, that's how it intended to work.

One may wonder why this is chosen to be a default setting, instead of preserving the structure of the original matrix. Consider the following example:

```
> apply(m, 1, quantile)
     [,1] [,2]
0%    1.0  2.0
25%   2.5  3.5
50%   4.0  5.0
75%   5.5  6.5
100%  7.0  8.0

> apply(m, 2, quantile)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
0%   1.00 3.00 5.00 7.00
25%  1.25 3.25 5.25 7.25
50%  1.50 3.50 5.50 7.50
75%  1.75 3.75 5.75 7.75
100% 2.00 4.00 6.00 8.00

> all(rownames(apply(m, 2, quantile)) == rownames(apply(m, 1, quantile)))
[1] TRUE
```

Consistent? Indeed, why would we expect anything else?

Comment: Thanks for explaining both the mechanics and reason. Unless subsequent consensus goes towards Matthew's (seemingly equally correct) answer I think you've nailed it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `apply` returns a matrix that is defined column-wise, and you're iterating over the rows.

The first application of `apply` presents each row, which is then a column in the result.

Presenting the function `print` shows what's being passed to `rev` at each iteration:

```
 x <- apply(m, 1, print)
[1] 1 3 5 7
[1] 2 4 6 8
```

That is, each call to print is passed a vector.  Two calls, and `c(1,3,5,7)` and `c(2,4,6,8)` are being passed to the function.

Reversing these gives `c(7,5,3,1)` and `c(8,6,4,2)`, then these are used as the columns of the return matrix, giving the result that you see.

Comment: Thanks Matthew I think you're spot on, but I think the answer belongs to tonytonov for articulating in terms of the documentation and illustrating the underlying philosophy. Incidentally the print thing was illuminating: `apply(m, 1, FUN=function(v){print("done")})` (confusingly) yields both printed and object reports which is something to bear in mind :)

Comment: @geotheory That's why I assigned the result to a variable.  This prevents printing the returned object.  In the case of experimenting with `print`, we only care about the arguments and not the returned value.  Wrapping the expression in `invisible()` also prevents printing the final result, but assigning to a variable is fewer keystrokes.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a row vector to rev, it returns a column vector.

```
t(c(1,2,3,4))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4

rev(t(c(1,2,3,4)))
[1] 4 3 2 1
```

which is not what you expected

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    3    2    1
```

So, you'll have to transpose the call to apply to get what you want

```
 t(apply(m, MARGIN=1, rev))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    7    5    3    1
[2,]    8    6    4    2
```

Comment: I see `t` forces a matrix orientation, but can `vec` itself be said to return a vertical or horizontal orientation?  `identical(1:10, rev(t(10:1)))` is TRUE.