# Converting a non-square matrix in a color matrix?

Tags: r

I am not able to plot a colormatrix starting from a non-square matrix. For example:

```
d<-read.table(text="
0  0.2  0.3  1 0.8
0.05  0.25  0.5  0.9 0
1  0.8  0.7  0.1 1 
1  1  0  1 0.5")
```

How can I convert it into a color matrix?

Comment: What is a color matrix?

Comment: I would like to achieve something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/30634155, but with a non-square matrix. Each value within the matrix should correspond to a shade of color going from white (0) to red (1), for example.