# R image function

Tags: r, image, plot

I have trouble understanding the image function in R. I have the following matrix

```
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] 6.931799 7.092166 7.136029 6.735593 6.621951 6.740000 6.049774 6.162304 6.169014 5.626374
[2,] 7.942623 7.909091 9.923077 5.888889 8.647059 8.166667 6.625000 6.529412 7.571429 5.590643
[3,] 8.446237 6.800000 9.000000 9.631579 8.892857 7.083333 6.857143 6.250000 6.413793 5.491525
[4,] 7.698276 6.666667 8.833333 7.565217 9.100000 6.705882 6.421053 7.045455 6.045455 5.267857
[5,] 6.082524 8.300000 8.250000 8.777778 7.250000 7.928571 6.500000 6.920000 5.041667 4.970833
[6,] 6.128571 8.636364 7.300000 6.266667 7.500000 7.384615 6.727273 6.312500 5.638889 4.569231
[7,] 6.146739 7.000000 7.625000 6.615385 5.466667 5.941176 7.100000 6.687500 5.789474 4.479675
[8,] 5.403509 7.714286 6.500000 8.500000 6.384615 7.133333 6.294118 5.900000 5.615385 4.759804
[9,] 5.444444 5.666667 4.875000 6.200000 6.777778 6.166667 5.642857 6.222222 5.428571 4.385093
[10,] 5.186180 5.621118 5.004878 5.045016 4.875433 4.594340 4.260377 4.276382 4.205128 3.632721
```

and I would like to display it as an heatmap. To so so I use the image function as following

```
image(1:10,1:10,mat,axes=FALSE)
```

but the result is definitly not what is in my matrix!![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MvQ7.png)

Any idea ?
thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is not right ... `image(1:10,1:10,mat,axes=FALSE)
text(expand.grid(1:10, 1:10), labels=as.vector(round(mat,2)))`

Comment: Check, use `fields` package to generate the legend.. `fields::image.plot(1:10,1:10,mat, col=heat.colors(12)) ; text(expand.grid(1:10, 1:10), labels=as.vector(round(mat,2)))` . Again looks okay??

Comment: Looks good to me, remember 1,1 is top left in your matrix but bottom left in your grid, so if you are simply overlaying them in your head it wouldn't look right.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(143)`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31882079/903061

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should keep in mind that the matrix is printed from top left but plotted from bottom left, like Badger has said. Increasing the row index would move you to the right on the plot.

The color intensity increases from red to white.

Another thing that you might want to change is the range on your z value. The plot takes the min and max values from your matrix and sets that as the default range. However, you might want to add the following argument: zlim=c(0,10)
, so that your range is from 0 to 10?

Lastly, if you want your plot to correspond to the locations of your z values in the matrix, you could create a new matrix where you rotate your original matrix by 90 degrees clockwise:
t(apply(mat, 2, rev))