# How to reverse rows in matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to reverse the order of the rows from the matrix m, so instead of getting this like in the following:

```
n <- rbind(m)
n

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
[3,]   11   12   13   14   15
[4,]   16   17   18   19   20
[5,]   21   22   23   24   25
```

I want to get this instead:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[5,]   21   22   23   24   25
[4,]   16   17   18   19   20
[3,]   11   12   13   14   15
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

Thanks for your help! Still learning the basics!

Comment: `m[nrow(m):1, ]` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can combine `apply()` and `rev()` to the matrix `n` and rearrange the entries:

```
n <- matrix(1:25, 5, byrow = TRUE)
apply(n,2,rev)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   21   22   23   24   25
#[2,]   16   17   18   19   20
#[3,]   11   12   13   14   15
#[4,]    6    7    8    9   10
#[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

By using `apply()` with the second parameter (the margin) equal to 2 we loop through all the columns of `n`, and for each column we apply the function `rev()`, which reverses the entries of a vector.

---

A more compact and faster way to obtain the same result is the solution pointed out by @Cath:

```
n[nrow(n):1,]
```

This simply reverses the order of the rows in the matrix.

Comment: not sure it will be more efficient than just `n[nrow(n):1, ]`...

Comment: Thank-you! Can you explain what apply() is doing a little? Sorry, still learning the basics.

Comment: @Cath I think you are right. Your solution with `n[nrow(n):1,]` should be more efficient. If you post it as an answer I'll upvote ;-)

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way I can think of to reverse the row order of a matrix `m` is:

```
m[nrow(m):1, ]
```

**some benchmark to compare the 2 options**

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(50000*100), ncol=100)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(n <- m[nrow(m):1, ], n <- apply(m, 2, rev), unit="relative")

#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# n <- m[nrow(m):1, ] 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100  a 
# n <- apply(m, 2, rev) 2.947735 3.090831 2.878977 3.143367 2.954659 1.816428   100   b
```