# R BasicStats function: How can statistics print statistics variable as the column

Tags: r

Here is the current R code and the result:

```
install.packages("fBasics")
library(fBasics)
basicStats(df)
#                    age height_seca1 height_chad1   height_DL weight_alog1
# nobs         29.000000    29.000000    29.000000   29.000000    29.000000
# NAs           0.000000     0.000000     0.000000    0.000000     0.000000
# Minimum      17.000000  1569.000000  1570.000000  155.000000    50.000000
# Maximum      31.000000  1877.000000  1880.000000  188.000000   106.000000
# 1. Quartile  19.000000  1666.000000  1665.000000  166.000000    65.000000
# 3. Quartile  21.000000  1816.000000  1809.000000  181.000000    80.000000
# Mean         20.413793  1737.241379  1736.482759  173.379310    73.413793
# Median       19.000000  1755.000000  1755.000000  175.000000    71.000000
# Sum         592.000000 50380.000000 50358.000000 5028.000000  2129.000000
# SE Mean       0.612910    17.069018    17.210707    1.798613     2.700354
# LCL Mean     19.158305  1702.277081  1701.228224  169.695018    67.882368
# UCL Mean     21.669282  1772.205677  1771.737293  177.063602    78.945219
# Variance     10.894089  8449.189655  8590.044335   93.815271   211.465517
# Stdev         3.300619    91.919474    92.682492    9.685828    14.541854
# Skewness      1.746597    -0.355499    -0.322915   -0.430019     0.560360
# Kurtosis      2.290686    -1.077820    -1.086108   -1.040182    -0.311017
```

Is it possible to print the above table in the following format (switch the row and column)?

```
# nobs         NAs          Minimum     Maximum      1. Quartile  3. Quartile Mean         Median       Sum         SE Mean       LCL Mean     UCL Mean Variance     Stdev        Skewness     Kurtosis     
# age ......
# height_seca1 ......
# height_chad1 ......
# height_DL ......
```

Comment: Try `t()`: `t(basicStats(mtcars))`. More on that [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)

Comment: @PoGibas, you can post that as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a Matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496210/rotate-a-matrix-in-r)

Comment: The solution works perfectly. Thanks!